# Index Exception that should not exist

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So e (this is not a question of what a index out of range exception it is why this specific one is happening when Im using the same index and method some where else Response to recent mark of repetition)

Essentially I am checking to see if a value in the array is Null. But it 
  keeps giving me an out of range exception when I just used the same 
  principle 
  in another area. This may be a silly question with a silly answer but I've 
  run into the issue and I seem to not be able to solve it.

I have checked that the int going in is correct and that the array is the 
  correct size.

Im sorry for lack of highlights Im new here and am not sure how to apply 
  them.`      The Place where it goes Wrong

```
public void OnDragStop()
  {
     if (SlotHover.name.Contains("Slot"))
     {
        string[] OS = PSlot.name.Split('t');
        int PSN = int.Parse(OS[1]);
        string[] NS = SlotHover.name.Split('t');
        SN = int.Parse(NS[1]);
        Debug.Log(SN);
        if (inventory.Inventoryitems[SN] == null)
        {
             inventory.Inventoryitems[SN] = 
              inventory.Inventoryitems[PSN];
              inventory.Inventoryitems[PSN] = null;
              SlotHover.transform.Find("ItemSlotSprite" + 
SN).GetComponent<Image>().sprite =
              PSlot.transform.Find("ItemSlotSprite" + 
PSN).GetComponent<Image>().sprite;
            PSlot.transform.Find("ItemSlotSprite" + 
SN).GetComponent<Image>().sprite = EmptySprite;
              this.gameObject.transform.position = PP;
        }

    }
}

The Place where its working 

 public void AddItem(Item ItemToAdd)
 {
    for(int i = 0; i < inventory.Inventoryitems.Length; i++)
    {
        if(inventory.Inventoryitems[i] == null)
        {
            inventory.Inventoryitems[i] = item;
            Sprite sprite = ItemToAdd.DefualtSprite;

Inventory.transform.Find("Slot"+i).transform.Find("ItemSlotSprite" + 
i).GetComponent<Image>().sprite = sprite;
            return;
        }
    }
}`
```

IndexOutOfRange: Array index out of range
  is what it gives me as shown above Im not sure why in this specific case 
  its giving the exception.

Comment: Hint: in the working code the variable `int i` is always within the valid index range ( >= 0 && < array.Length). This cannot be said for the non working code - one of the `SN` or `PSN` variables is outside the valid index range, hence the exception.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to check inventory lenght

```
if(inventory.Inventoryitems.Length >0){
for(int i = 0; i < inventory.Inventoryitems.Length; i++)
    {
        if(inventory.Inventoryitems[i] == null)
        {
            inventory.Inventoryitems[i] = item;
            Sprite sprite = ItemToAdd.DefualtSprite;

Inventory.transform.Find("Slot"+i).transform.Find("ItemSlotSprite" + 
i).GetComponent<Image>().sprite = sprite;
            return;
        }
    }
}
```